# PKPayment doesn't always return a name

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay, passkit

When creating my `PKPaymentRequest` I specify some required fields like this:

```
request.requiredBillingAddressFields = PKAddressFieldPostalAddress|PKAddressFieldEmail|PKAddressFieldName;
request.requiredShippingAddressFields = PKAddressFieldEmail|PKAddressFieldName;
```

Note: I only need billing email and name but if I don't specify the `PKAddressFieldEmail|PKAddressFieldName` on `requiredShippingAddressFields` as well the ApplePay UI does not ask for this.

Then I try to extract the name like this. It is not always clear if it arrives in the shipping address or the billing address so I check for both.

```
NSString *name = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABRecordCopyCompositeName(payment.shippingAddress);
if (!name) {
    name = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABRecordCopyCompositeName(payment.billingAddress);
}
```

But sometimes the name just doesn't show up. It's intermittent, sometimes it does show up, sometimes it does not without changing anything. This makes me suspect it's a bug in iOS 8.4 but I'm definitely not ruling out it's my fault. (It usually is.)

Has anyone else run into this? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I don't know why you are not getting it, Although I have a strong feeling it could be a bug.
I am facing an issue in apple pay too and it was working well before iOS 8.4.
My issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760725/pkpaymentauthorizationviewcontroller-is-crashing-unexpectedly-on-ios-8-4

Comment: I'm seeing this both in the simulator and on device in iOS 9.2.